# jenking unable to check out from github

Tags: git, jenkins, github, svn

I am trying to create job in Jenkins which would checkout from github. While doing so I am encountering below exception. Below is the url I configured in 'source code management' > Repository URL tab 'https://github.com/javahometech/my-app.git'

Any suggestion would be helpful.

```
<code> 
[WS-CLEANUP] Done
Checking out a fresh workspace because there's no workspace at C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\gitdemo
Cleaning local Directory .
Checking out https://github.com/efsavage/hello-world-war.git at revision '2020-05-24T02:29:22.302 +0530' --quiet
ERROR: Failed to check out https://github.com/efsavage/hello-world-war.git
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E200007: Server does not support date-based operations
svn: E200007: The requested report is unknown.
svn: E175002: REPORT of '/efsavage/hello-world-war.git/!svn/vcc/default': 400 Bad Request (https://github.com)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:112)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:96)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getDatedRevision(DAVRepository.java:196)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNBasicDelegate.getRevisionNumber(SVNBasicDelegate.java:475)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNBasicDelegate.getLocations(SVNBasicDelegate.java:838)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNBasicDelegate.createRepository(SVNBasicDelegate.java:527)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.doCheckout(SVNUpdateClient16.java:875)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:66)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:18)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:927)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:857)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:505)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1205)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1853)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:427)
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E200007: Server does not support date-based operations
svn: E200007: The requested report is unknown.
svn: E175002: REPORT of '/efsavage/hello-world-war.git/!svn/vcc/default': 400 Bad Request (https://github.com)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:112)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:96)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getDatedRevision(DAVRepository.java:196)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNBasicDelegate.getRevisionNumber(SVNBasicDelegate.java:475)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNBasicDelegate.getLocations(SVNBasicDelegate.java:838)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNBasicDelegate.createRepository(SVNBasicDelegate.java:527)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.doCheckout(SVNUpdateClient16.java:875)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:66)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:18)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1239)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$SubversionUpdateTask.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:130)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to check out https://github.com/efsavage/hello-world-war.git
    at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$SubversionUpdateTask.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:141)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:168)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:176)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:427)
Finished: FAILURE</code>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you're seeing is that the Jenkins plugin you're using is attempting to use a date-based format to specify the Subversion revision, and GitHub doesn't support those.  GitHub uses it's own Subversion to Git bridge, and date-based operations aren't implemented because Git commits need not have monotonically increasing timestamps.  It's therefore not possible in all cases to decide what revision a timestamp should point to.

You could check out this repository as a Git repository and it would likely work fine.  Alternatively, you could try a different Subversion plugin that doesn't use date-based formats, if one exists.